# What is the purpose of th HTTP GET method in forms?

Tags: c#, http, post, get, httplistener

As far as I understand, the GET method asks the server to send something to the client's browser. I set up a HTTPListener in C# and when I access http://localhost:1330/form.html the request I get from the client is: `GET /form.html` which means that the client is saying "Hey server, I need the HTML code to display that page in the browser", which makes sense.

If I set a `<form>` with `method=POST` in *form.html*, the input fields values are located in the request body which is in `context.Request.InputStream` in C# which looks similar to this: `input_name1=value&input_name2=value2&input_name3=value3...` and the URL remains `/form.html`.

This also makes sense. The client says: "Hey server, take this data that was written in the HTML `<input>` elements" and the server uses it, maybe storing it in a database or computing something and send it back to the client.

Now *if* I set the form method to GET, the URL is modified to: `/form.html?input_name1=value&input_name2=value2&input_name3=value3` and the `context.Request.InputStream` remains blank which is the opposite of the POST, in which the InputStream contained the data and the URL had no queries. For me, the GET method in forms doesn't make any sense. Why do we need to get the data from the form client side, send it to the server and then getting it back to client unmodified? Why do I send the data from the browser to C# and then sending it back to browser, if I can just get it client side using simple JavaScript?

In the moment the browser makes the GET request with the queries to the server, the client browser already has that data, so why does it ask the server to give it if it is already at the client's browser?

Comment: "Why do we need to get the data from the form client side, send it to the server and then getting it back to client unmodified" I don't see where you get that data back from the server. You surely have to provide some data to the server. Using GEt you'll do that using the URL-params, using POST you're using the requests body. On the server-side there's no difference (at least not much in scope of this question).

Comment: I thought the GET method is just for the client to receive something from the server.

Comment: sure, but in order to recieve that something, you have to provide something as well, depending on that server. Why do you expect the GET-request to not needing anything, while a similar POST-request needs some data?

Comment: Or in other words: a GET-request can of course also have params. Think of requesting some resource from a server. Of course you have to provide the name of that resource in some way - which using GET would be via an URL-param.

Comment: For getting the HTML for a page, for instance, the GET method needs to provide the page : `/form.html`, If GET used in forms, just sends not receive, why is called GET then?

Comment: I think I understood. As far as I understand, POST and GET in many cases can switch places and often the system would work with both of them. For example, I can use GET to send the data to server and then store it in SQL in C# side and then send the response back to the client saying, "Your data: [data goes here] was successfully registered", and I can use POST, which I guess is more common for this action.

Comment: @BogdanFloareș also this has nothing to do with C#. It's HTML + HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, an HTTP GET method is used to receive data from the server, while an HTTP POST is used to modify data or add data to a resource.

For example, think about a search form. There may be some fields on the form used to filter the results, such as `SearchTerm`, `Start/EndDate`,  `Category`, `Location`, `IsActive`, etc, etc.  You're requesting the results from the server, but not modifying any of the data. Those fields will be added to the GET request by the client so the server can filter and return the results you requested.

From the MDN article [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data):

> Each time you want to reach a resource on the Web, the browser sends a
> request to a URL. An HTTP request consists of two parts: a header that
> contains a set of global metadata about the browser's capabilities,
> and a body that can contain information necessary for the server to
> process the specific request.

GET requests do not have a request body, so the parameters are added to the URL (this is defined in the [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9), if you're interested).

> The GET method is the method used by the browser to ask the server to
> send back a given resource: "Hey server, I want to get this resource."
> In this case, the browser sends an empty body. Because the body is
> empty, if a form is sent using this method the data sent to the server
> is appended to the URL.

An HTTP POST method uses the request body to add the parameters.  Typically in a POST you will be adding a resource, or modifying an existing resource.

> The POST method is a little different. It's the method the browser
> uses to talk to the server when asking for a response that takes into
> account the data provided in the body of the HTTP request: "Hey
> server, take a look at this data and send me back an appropriate
> result." If a form is sent using this method, the data is appended to
> the body of the HTTP request.

There are plenty of resources online to learn about the HTTP protocol and HTTP verbs/methods. The MDN articles [An overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview), [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data), and [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) should provide some good introductory reading material.

Comment: "You're requesting the results from the server". I think I understood. I send the data similar to the POST method, however the GET part is in obtaining the results based on that data.

Comment: however I don't see why POST can't be used to send search terms to a server

Comment: Of course it could be used. But it's not what the spec recommends.  If you use GET for search term then I could share the URL with you and we'd get the same results. You can't share a POST request as easily because it uses the request body for the params, and POST is meant to be used when data is being modified. You're not modifying any data when you ask the server "send me some stuff"